# Validation of characters in a text field

Tags: javascript, validation

i am new at programming and my I think my question is easy, but I don't have any ideas. How to check if the number of characters in a text field matches 11? I tried this but I don't think that's a good lead.

```
<form name="formz">
         <input type='text' name='numbere' id="p"  maxlength="11">  
</form> 

<button onclick="writee()">x</button>
        <script>
function writee(){


    win=window.open(" ","tab","width=300,height=350")
      win.document.open()



 var l = document.forms["formz"].numbere;
 if(l.length==11){
    win.document.write( "under 11 characters <br/>");
 }else{
    win.document.write( " 11 characters <br/>");
 }
}
```

Comment: `<input minlength="11" maxlength="11" />` done.

Answer (score 0):

Add `minLength="11"` to the same input.

Note that if you need more secure validation, you will also have to check the values on the server side.  The Html attributes will only work for client-side validation.  This means that someone who is determined to circumvent the length requirements could edit the source code in their browser and bypass your restrictions.  For more casual use cases that are not security sensitive, the HTML attributes should suffice.

Comment: The point of client-side validation is to provide a more user-friendly experience, and avoid wasting time sending things to the server that the browser can immediately determine are gonna get rejected. It's not about security, it's about usability. Of course, security should always be a server-side matter. Never trust the browser.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of HTML please have a look at the input's attributes:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input

In JavaScript it has been answered here:
[Form Validation Vanilla JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39988675/form-validation-vanilla-js)

To further your knowledge about Regex validation, here are some examples:
https://regex101.com/library?orderBy=RELEVANCE&page=1&search=validation